# Error: "undefined reference to `gluNewQuadric@0'"

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw, sfml

I have an errors during compilation of OpenGL SFML C++ project in Eclipse (using MinGW as toolchain):

> undefined reference to `gluNewQuadric@0'
>
> undefined reference to `gluQuadricDrawStyle@8'
>
> undefined reference to `gluDeleteQuadric@4

The offending code is here:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>   
 
sf::WindowSettings Settings;
Settings.AntialiasingLevel = 2;
Settings.DepthBits = 24;
Settings.StencilBits = 8;
sf::Window  App(sf::VideoMode(1024, 768, 32), "SFML Window", sf::Style::Close, Settings);
App.SetFramerateLimit(30);
prepareGL(App.GetWidth(), App.GetHeight());
sf::Clock Clock;
App.SetActive();
// GL goes here:
GLUquadricObj *qw1 = gluNewQuadric();
gluQuadricDrawStyle(qw1,GLU_POINT);
App.Display();
while (App.IsOpened()) {
    sf::Event Event;
    while (App.GetEvent(Event)) {
        if (((Event.Type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
            && (Event.Key.Code == sf::Key::Escape))
            || (Event.Type == sf::Event::Closed)) {
            gluDeleteQuadric(qw1);
            App.Close();
        }
        if (Event.Type == sf::Event::Resized) {
            glViewport(0, 0, Event.Size.Width, Event.Size.Height);
        }
    }
}
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

What I did wrong? Usually, I code in Java, and this project I am doing for learning more about C/C++. I did other OpenGL programs before, and I had no problems like that before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass appropriate flag to the compiler. To include the GLU library, pass this to the compiling and linking options :

```
-lGLU
```

EDIT : The above works on linux, but for windows, it is :

```
-lglu32
```

Comment: Did't helped... `**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -Wl,--subsystem,windows -mwindows -o src\main.o ..\src\main.cpp
g++ -o OpenGL.exe src\main.o -lsfml-graphics-s-d -lsfml-window-s-d -lsfml-system-s-d -lGLU
c:/program files/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lGLU`

Comment: @DoktorNo Do you have GLU and opengl libraries installed?

Comment: @DoktorNo use -lglu32 instead, windows has its own naming for the opengl libraries  (-lGLU works on linux)

Comment: @VJovic As I said, I did few OpenGL programs before using exactly the same setup. Until I made this program, that was supposed to use GLUquadricObj... I thought, that SFML gives everything OpenGL-related in Window.hpp: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.3/window-opengl.php

Comment: How would you add this flag in cmake? I am new to cmake and trying to compile g20 on ubuntu.